# ORACLE 10g Not displaying data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

I have the following query and it is not displaying any records yet they exist.

```
SELECT movieID, actorID, title, lastName, firstName, gender 
FROM Actor, Movie
WHERE title ='Midnight Cowboy';
```

please note this is not the same as my previous question as that was to view data from two filed this is not working as its not displaying any data.

I have run this query:

```
SELECT movieID, actorID, title, lastName, firstName, gender 
FROM Actor, Movie
WHERE lastName ='Hoffman';
```

It shows the movie Midnight Cowboys plus all other movies associated with him there are two actors in this movie which is what i want The second query shows the second actor:

```
SELECT movieID, actorID, title, lastName, firstName, gender 
FROM Actor, Movie
WHERE lastName ='Voight';
```

This shows all the movies that he is in plus Midnight Cowboys

Thats why i was trying to bring up the actors for Midnight Cowboys movie only

Here is the info from the spool file and i have tried Midnight Cowboys also with teh query does not show data:

MOV TITLE                                      YEAR

---

COMPANY                                             TOTALNOMS  AWARDSWON

---

DVDPRICE DISCOUNTPRICE

---

025 Midnight Cowboys                           1969
Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer                                         5          2
     17.99         11.99

Comment: No rows are displayed as it says on the question it is not displaying any records

Comment: Sorry I did not know if you allow me to i can change it but it wont allow it

Comment: Anyway you need to define some relation between Actor and Movie in your query, unless you want a FULL OUTER JOIN.

Comment: Because when i run this SELECT movieID, actorID, title, lastName, firstName, gender 
FROM Actor, Movie
WHERE lastName ='Hoffman'; it shows the movie Midnight Cowboys there are two actors in this movie which is what i want The second query shows the second actor:


SELECT movieID, actorID, title, lastName, firstName, gender 
FROM Actor, Movie
WHERE lastName ='Voight'; and it shows all the movies that he is in plus Midnight Cowboys

Thats why i was trying to bring up the actors for that movie only

Comment: All i desire is a method in which these two actors are shown for  the movie Midnight Cowboys but i dont know how

Comment: @user1137472 , so maybe it's spelled "Midnight Cowboys" like you say, not "Midnight Cowboy" like you have in your query ? Anyway, you need to show us the data, not tell us about it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query and see if it returns anything:

```
SELECT movieID, actorID, title, lastName, firstName, gender 
FROM Actor, Movie
WHERE UPPER(title) LIKE '%MIDNIGHT%COWBOY%';
```

Assuming it does, compare the movie title **EXACTLY** to what you were using in your example (i.e. `Midnight Cowboy`) and see where your comparison was incorrect.

Hope it helps...

EDIT:

OK, having seen your comments on this answer and the OP.

This query `SHOULD` return the data you need:

```
SELECT Actor.firstName,
       Actor.middleName,
       Actor.lastName,
       Movie.title
  FROM Actor
 INNER JOIN Role ON (Actor.actorID = Role.actorID)
 INNER JOIN Movie ON (Role.movieID = Movie.movieID)
 WHERE (Movie.title = 'Midnight Cowboys'
       OR UPPER(Movie.title) LIKE '%MIDNIGHT%COWBOY%');
```

If it returns nothing then I'd suggest you have a data issue.
Try this query to make sure you have at least one record linking the movies to actors via their roles (BTW you should not name the table "Role" as it is an Oracle reserved word).
If it returns no rows then you are missing your linking data and have more issues than just the question you have posted.

```
SELECT *
  FROM Role
 WHERE movieID = '025';
```

N.B. I have assumed the `movieID` column is a `VARCHAR2` column due to the `movieID` apparently appearing as `025` in the results you posted in your original question, if it were a numeric it would have been `25`.

Comment: sorry I didn't see your answer till today will try thank you and let you know

Comment: @user1137472 - then you must have run that query incorrectly, or misrepresented the results of your actor-only queries in the question, or deleted tha data since running those. (Or you inserted in another session and didn't ever commit). Add the actual results of one of the actor-only queries to the question.

Comment: The movie is stored within the database if i query the movie it is there but so are the actors but i cant query both actors from one movie the data has not been deleted and no i didn't run the query incorrectly Look at my edited question thanks

Comment: I have also tried this:



SELECT movieID, actorID, title, lastName, firstName, gender FROM Actor JOIN Movie on actorID = actorID WHERE (lastName ='Hoffman' OR lastName ='Voight') AND title ='Midnight Cowboy';

But did not work

Comment: Post the structure of both the `ACTOR` and `MOVIE` tables please?

Comment: Ok will do I post scheme of my database

Comment: Actor (actorID, lastName, firstName, middleName, suffix, gender, birthDate, deathDate)
Movie (movieID, title, year, company, totalNoms, awardsWon, DVDPrice, discountPrice)
Quote (quoteID, quote)
Role (roleID ,roleName ,gender ,actorID* ,movieID*) 
RoleQuote (roleID*, quoteID*)